# Why is my font not appearing as it did on google fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I have gotten two fonts from google fonts, and have applied them to my CSS document. Then I added them to my document, but they don't show up as what appeared on the website for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@500&family=Libre+Baskerville&display=swap');

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
}
```

Here is the link to both fonts:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Baskerville?query=libre+bas&preview.text=Lorem%20Ipsum&preview.text_type=custom

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/League+Spartan?query=league+&preview.text=Lorem%20Ipsum&preview.text_type=custom

Comment: Hi, there! It is currently hard to help you with the information you just shared. Could you try to add more in order to make it possible to reproduce your error? How are you importing the CSS? Are you on React/Vue/Angular..?

Comment: A lot can go wrong here, from network errors to overwriting your styles. So more information / details are needed.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/cikakonule/1/edit?html,css,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: you should look at your browser Inspector for some diagnosis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what it is:
The @import has to be at the top of the stylesheet, before any other css.